# Office Application hangs during document opening on german windows, works on english one

Tags: c#, wcf, service, ms-word, office-interop

We found a bug in our service that only seems to be existing in a German version of Microsoft Windows. Here's the code:

```
public Application OpenApplicationWithFile(object filename)
{
    object _missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Application objWord = new Application();
    objWord.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
    objWord.Application.Visible = false;
    objWord.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref _readOnly, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing,
                                   ref _missing,
                                   ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _isVisible,
                                   ref _missing,
                                   ref _missing, ref _missing,
                                   ref _missing, ref _missing);
    return objWord;
}
```

The debugger hangs on the *Documents.Open()* call, and just stays there waiting - without firing any type of exception or error. We have looked in the event log but only found the following:

> Das Dokument 'convert1002.doc' verursachte ein Problem, als es zuletzt
>   geöffnet wurde. Möchten Sie mit dem Öffnen fortfahren?

which translates via google translate to:

> The document 'convert1002.doc' caused a serious error last time it was
>   opened. Would you like to continue opening it?

So, it would seem that Word just asked the user something, however since it is invisible the user can't exactly click yes or no. Changing the *objWord.Application.Visible* value to *true* doesn't change anything - the word process is still invisible. So my question is how to investigate what is the reason for this scenario and how to fix it. Thanks for any input.

Comment: Are you doing any OpenXML document generation / modding in your service?  I found once that we can code which was calling .ToString() on a number and setting an Open XML attribute to this string -- in European countries this would cause an error because it using commas instead of decimals, we had to switch to using ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).

Comment: .NET 4 and named parameters makes it no longer necessary to specify `ref _missing`

Answer (score 3):

This error can occur in every Language-Version and depending on the Word-Version you use, it may not be easy to prevent hidden dialogs. Which Word-Version do you use?

But first, your parameters are off by one (i think). ReadOnly is the third parameter and thats why _isVisible my not be working.

I tried to set objWord.Application.Visible to true and it worked for me. Maybe something else is wrong too?

One quick solution may be setting OpenAndRepair to true. Its the 13. Parameter, right behind isVisible.

Otherwise have a look at this Link: 
[How To Dismiss a Dialog Box Displayed by an Office Application with Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259971/en-us).

Comment: Hi, and thanks for reading my question and taking the time to answer. We are using Office 2010 Professional Plus. You were right, I have messed up my parameters, however after fixing them the problem persists. My assumption is that I can't see the window because the dialog box is displayed before the window has a chance to open. Does that make sense? I will continue investigating.

Answer (score 2):

This issue might be similar to what was discussed here [Interop.Word Documents.Open stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916416/interop-word-documents-open-stuck/17780642#17780642)

When you try to open the file using the German version do you attempt to open the same file?

Try opening a different file.

Other things to try setting:

```
objWord.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsAll;
```

AND/OR try setting the openandrepair to true as mentioned by Uwe:

```
Object obOpenAndRepair = true;
Document doc = word.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref _readOnly,
                    ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing,
                    ref _missing, ref _missing, ref oMissing,  ref _missing,ref _isVisible,
                    ref obOpenAndRepair, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing);
```

Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reading. We have already tried both of those solutions and neither of them work. The issue is even weirder, as we have prepared two clean virtual machines - one with german windows 7 enterprise, second with an english windows 7 enterprise. Then we installed the english version of Office 2010 Professional Plus on both of those - so the only difference is the language of the OS. Updated everything, set up our service, and tested - our code works on the english os, doesn't work on the german. I am out of ideas.

Comment: Oh that is strange good luck with it. let us know if you find out the problem.